# Correct appendix numbering

Tags: formatting, page-numbering

I am trying to obtain specific page numbering in my appendix. Currently my appendix page numbering in the appendix is Alph. I want to obtain page numbering that is consistent with the appendix title.

i.e. for appendix A the the pages should be numbered A-1, A-2, A-3...etc,
     for appendix B the the pages should be numbered B-1, B-2, B-3...etc

My code thus far looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

body of document...

\clearpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix A}
\pagenumbering{Alph}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What if two appendices are on the same page? ;-) How do you define the appendix name? Automatic as uppercase letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each appendix will start in a new page, this achieves what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

body of document...

\clearpage
\appendix

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{page}{section}
\makeatother  
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{\oldsection[#1]{#2}\stepcounter{page}}

\section{Appendix A}

\newpage
Second page, first appendix
\newpage

\section{Appendix B}

\newpage
Second page, second appendix

\end{document}
```